# Zeroclipboard grays out button on hover and active

Tags: javascript, html, css, zeroclipboard

When you hover over my button it gets grayed out. Also as you click it. I am using zeroclipboard v1.3.5
code: Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#copy_button"), {
moviePath: "zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});     
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p class="baddress">18b1bypQA52LdYBnth8sqt2zDvZVZStpZe <button class="btca"      id="copy_button" data-clipboard-text="18b1bypQA52LdYBnth8sqt2zDvZVZStpZe" title="Click to     copy me.">Copy</button></p>
```

CSS

```
.btca, .zeroclipboard-is-hover{
background-color: #61ff21;
border: 3px solid black;
border-color: #00ffff;
text-decoration: none;
color:gray;
font-weight: bold;
}
.btca:active, .zeroclipboard-is-active{
border-color: #61ff21;
background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

Comment: Is CSS working in the `active` state?

Comment: @FahadHasan It works if i do not have zeroclipboard. But with zeroclipboard it doesn't work with hover or active even with `.zeroclipboard-is-active`

Comment: did you try specifying the styles separately to `.btca:hover`, `btca:active`, `.zeroclipboard-is-hover` and `.zeroclipboard-is-active`? Like this: `.btca:hover { //styles here } .zeroclipboard-is-hover { //styles here } btca:active { //styles here } .zeroclipboard-is-active { //styles here }`.

Comment: @FahadHasan yes i've tried that and it did not work